# Support bundling for non-webpack users in workbox-cli

Tags: workbox

I am running the below command on my dist directory.

`workbox copyLibraries dist/en-in/; workbox generateSW workbox-config-prod.js;`

The service worker file calls

`importScripts("/workbox-v4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");`

workbox-sw.js downloads below files:

```
   workbox-core.prod.js
   workbox-precaching.prod.js
   workbox-routing.prod.js
   workbox-strategies.prod.js
   workbox-expiration.prod.js
   workbox-cacheable-response.prod.js"
```

**Question 1:**

I have set long expiry cache headers on all files served from /workbox-v4.3.1/ path
since it is versioned. Is there any downside to this approach?

**Question 2:**

Can Workbox provide support for teams which don't use any bundlers?

If workbox-cli can output a single file which has 
1. Only those Workbox modules which as referenced in the workbox-config file. 
2. Code generated from the workbox-config file. 
3. Minified
This was how sw-precache used to generate service worker file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have set long expiry cache headers on all files served from
>   /workbox-v4.3.1/ path since it is versioned. Is there any downside to
>   this approach?

There's no downside to that approach because, as you mention, the `/v4.3.1/` path segment is used in your URL, so the content should never change. There is some nuance around whether or not URLs loaded via `importScripts()` (which happens for all of the Workbox URLs) are actually checked for updates, and that's detailed more in [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/fresher-sw#checks_for_updates_to_imported_scripts). But what you're doing with `Cache-Control` headers should be fine.

> Can Workbox provide support for teams which don't use any bundlers?

That's straightforward with Workbox v5 (as of Nov. 2019, in pre-release), using `generateSW` with the following configuration:

```
{
  inlineWorkboxRuntime: true,
  mode: 'production',
  sourcemap: false,
  // ...other options...
}
```

That will generate a single service worker file that includes the Workbox runtime inline, minified, without a sourcemap, which is about as straightforward as the output gets. Under the hood, Workbox will use Rollup for you to create a custom bundle that only contains the parts of Workbox that you actually need, so you don't have to worry about doing bundling yourself.